# setInterval() causes my page to lag

Tags: jquery, scroll, setinterval, lag

I need to keep checking the scroll position of the document. My code is currently:

```
setInterval(function(){ check() }, 1000);
function check() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop()  >700) {
       // do something, like drop down a menu or whatever
    }
    if ($(document).scrollTop() <= 700) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

It makes my webpage very laggy. Are there any alternative ways to check a user's scrolling position that use fewer resources?

Comment: A quick comment: I believe it's slightly better to use `setInterval(check, 1000)` than to use `setInterval(function(){ check() }, 1000)`, when there are no specific arguments to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

The `window` object has an [`onScroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onscroll) event that you can listen for. For example:

```
var $document = $(document);
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if ($document.scrollTop() > 700) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
});
```

Also, note that storing the return value of `$(document)` and re-using it will provide a slight increase in performance.

Comment: but using the scroll event listener means it check every 1 ms whenever user scroll, isn't it is same bad performance?

Comment: This way you're only checking when you know something has changed, rather than checking repeatedly just in case it has. This has the added benefit that your actions will take place the moment they scroll, rather than a short time afterwards.

I'll update this answer with a jsFiddle link when I have some time later, if you want?